# Why is wecomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js not working

Tags: javascript, polymer, babeljs, custom-element, polymer-2.x

I converting a Polymer app to Polymer 2. I'm changing my components to the ES6 Class syntax (yes I know I could leave them in v1.7 hybrid style but I would like them to be ES6 Classes).

**However** when I transpile the code back to ES5 (with BabelJS) I run into a known issue regarding ES5 'classes' extending native elements (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4480).

I tried babel-plugin-transform-custom-element-classes but that didn't work.
**So I tried the webcomponents shim meant to fix this issue:** https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs

But the shim doesn't work! I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

```
<script src="webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
...
<y-example></y-example>
...
<script>
  /* transpiled to ES5 */
  class YExample extends HTMLElement {}
  customElements.define('y-example', YExample);
</script>
```

Here is my jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/feqoniz/edit?html,js,output

Notice I'm including the custom-elements-es5-adapter.js,
also notice the JS panel is using ES6/Babel.

If you remove the custom-elements-es5-adapter.js and change the JS panel to normal Javascript (not ES6/Babel) then everything works fine.

You can include or remove the adapter (leaving ES6/Babel) and the error is basically the same thing, except that when the adapter is included it comes from the adapter code instead: **Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.**

I must be doing something silly? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was doing something silly.. I should have tried upgrading my Babel package.

Upgraded BabelJS from 6.23.1 to latest 6.24.1 and it fixed the problem. :P

Answer (score 1):

I was stucked with the same issue.

The problem was due to my build chain (gulp) transpiling every js files of the project. But the custom-elements-es5-adapter.js file **must not** be transpiled to work. Transpile everything but this file.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue and I found a solution that works for me.

Disclaimer: I don't use an app-shell because I have a server-side rendered site with just a few isolated Polymer components on the client-side.

After intense debugging the issue came down to the fact that I was including this block (as suggested on the Polymer guides):

```
<div id="autogenerated-ce-es5-shim">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (!window.customElements) {
      var ceShimContainer = document.querySelector('#autogenerated-ce-es5-shim');
      ceShimContainer.parentElement.removeChild(ceShimContainer);
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
</div>
```

Because when I ran `polymer build` it would pick up `custom-elements-es5-adapter.js` from there.

This is what I did instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.customElements) {
   document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
}
</script>
```

YES it's not as elegant and quite rustic but, hey, it works! Here I'm tricking the compilers inside `polymer build` and they won't find this file and hence they won't include it in the build.

I hope it helps!